# DHT22 not working on Raspberry Pi2

Tags: raspbian, gpio, dht22

I have DHT22 sensor hooked up to my Raspberry Pi2 running default Raspbian image. I have similar setup on Raspberry Pi B and it is working. I am using Adafruit library for DH22. However when I try running the code to read data from DHT22 I get the following exception (using the example code that comes with library):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AdafruitDHT.py", line 41, in <module>
    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, pin)
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_DHT/common.py", line 90, in read_retry
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_DHT/common.py", line 77, in read
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_DHT/Raspberry_Pi_2.py", line 34, in read
RuntimeError: Error accessing GPIO.
```

I have found on internet that the exception it related to lack of permission and that running the code as sudo should fix the problem. But I had no luck so far with it.

I have tried running the code as:

**1.**

```
python AdafruitDHT.py 2302 4
```

**2.**

```
sudo python AdafruitDHT.py 2302 4
```

**3.**

```
su -
python AdafruitDHT.py 2302 4
```

However all ways yield the same exception. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried using a different GPIO?  Don't move the DHT22, just check if giving a different GPIO number gives the same error.

Comment: Yes, I have tried several GPIO ports and the exception is always the same.

Comment: Can't help.  You need to see if you can access the GPIO with other software and try to localise the problem.

Comment: I have tried the pigpio library that I assume you created? However I am now getting readings of -999. I will check the wiring and try another sensor  to exclude problem with my setup.

Comment: -999 means no reading.  Probably because pigpio only uses (Broadcom) GPIO numbering.  See http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/#Type_3.  I suggest you use http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#pdif2_DHTXXD with pigpio.

Comment: I had to add -lrt to build command in order to build DHTXXD. This is not in your readme file (typo maybe?). When I run the DHTXXD as: ./DHTXXD -g4 I get no output. I have also tried using other ports and result stays the same.

Comment: Okay.  A photo will help.  Simplest set up is power from 3V3 and ground, 4k7 resistor from GPIO4 (pin 7) to 3V3, and wire from GPIO4 to DHT data.  If that doesn't work I'd say you have a duff device but a photo will help.

Comment: I have a 10K resistor and 5V. Will take pictures tomorrow.